# ¿Como interpretar el array que devuelve la función cv2.findContours?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.8

tengo el siguiente código:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image= cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Ezequiel\\Desktop\\mejorado.png')
original=image.copy()
gray=cv2.cvtColor(original,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold_aplicado,thresholded_image=cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    
cnts=cv2.findContours(thresholded_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts=cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1] #(findContours devuelve contours y hierarchy)
```

Se que el findContours me devuelve una lista con 2 elementos, por un lado los contornos, y por otro lado la herencia. Imprimo el primer elemento de los contornos:

```
print(cnts[0])

[[[1050  466]]

 [[1049  467]]

 [[1049  468]]

 [[1051  468]]

 [[1051  466]]]
```

Sé que cada uno de estos 5 elementos representa una coordenada en la imagen, pero mi pregunta es, ¿no debería devolver 4 puntos,dado que es un rectángulo? ¿Precisamente qué coordenada representa cada uno de estos 5 elementos? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación, el retorno de [`contours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) es básicamente:

> Detected contours. Each contour is stored as a vector of points.

Es decir, son los contornos detectados, cada uno gestionado como un vector de puntos (que se conectan entre ellos). Ahora, tus preguntas:

> ¿no debería devolver 4 puntos,dado que es un rectángulo? ¿Precisamente
> qué coordenada representa cada uno de estos 5 elementos?

Si, un rectángulo debiera ser descripto por un contorno mínimo de 4 puntos, pero siempre que sea un forma perfecta, sin artefactos que lo distorsionaran,tal vez analizando la imagen se podría apreciar esto. Sino, lo que puedes hacer es dibujar cada uno de los puntos de los contornos:

```
contornos, hierachy  = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contorno in contornos:
  for puntos in contorno:
    for punto in puntos:
      x, y = punto
      cv2.circle(gray,(x,y), 3, (0,0,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('Puntos', gray)
```

Con `cv2.circle(imagen,)centro, radio, color)` puedes dibujar un circulo en cada punto, ajusta el radio en función de la dimensión de la imagen, para que esos puntos sean visibles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!